# Log transformation in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, data-transformation

I have a model with a natural log transformed variable in a logistic regression and I'm looking for some help in interpreting the odds ratio. The odds ratio is 1.78 (coefficient 0.58). I know there are similar questions on this list however I just wanted to check how to interpret in the situation of using natural logs. many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The odds ratio will be the ratio of the odds per 1 point increase in the natural log of whatever the variable is. Say it's log income. Then the OR is for a change of income from \$10,000 to \$27,183; or \$20,000 to \$54,366 etc.